# Как реализовать продвинутую работу с формами в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Появилась интересная задачка с которой ранее не сталкивался. Реализую "сложную форму", то форма состоит из нескольких шагов (планируется 3-4 шага) и поля на каждом следующем шаге будут зависит от выбора определенных пунктов на предыдущем.

Заполненные формы необходимо будет сохранять и самое интересное, перед отправкой введенные данные необходимо конвертировать в `json` и отправлять по определенному `API`.

В c формами в WordPress работал (в основном `ContactForm` + `Flamingo`, если требуется сохранение форм), но подобный функционал не реализовывал. Попытался реализовать сложную форму через contact form - не вышло и не знаю есть ли готовые плагины под такого рода задачи...

Поэтому сейчас рассматриваю создание данной формы с помощью `ACF` (опишу необходимые поля и буду выводить их согласно требуемых условий). Ввиду этого возникло несколько вопросов:

- Подскажите насколько "правильный" подход - реализации формы через `ACF` (возможно есть лучшие практики)?
- Как логичнее реализовать сохранение заполненной формы. У меня на уровне идеи пока - создать кастомный тип записи с двумя полями (заголовок / контент (куда будет помещаться заявка)?
- По поводу передачи данных введенных в форме по `API`. В целом логика понятна данные прогоняем через `wp_json_encode()`, и отдаем на нужный адрес, но это теория. Кто реализовывал подобный функционал на практике, могли бы поделится опытом или ткнуть носом в статью?

Буду очень признателен, кто поделится опытом реализации подобного функционала или части функционала.

Comment: https://wpforms.com/how-to-create-a-multi-part-form-in-wordpress/

Comment: К CF7 есть кучу разных разных аддонов Например https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/ https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/ и другие. Есть офигительный, но относительно сложный самостоятельный плаг https://wordpress.org/plugins/cforms2/.

Comment: Спасибо большое за рекомендации, попробую.